# Automatically Tagging a PR Build in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have branch validation in the form of a PR Build, which means I have duplicated my original build and removed some steps (such as pushing to my docker registry).

I would prefer to simply be able to automatically add a tag / some kind of identifier to a PR build and exclude the step on the original build using custom conditions.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how to achieve it? I'd really rather not duplicate each and every build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to run a build step based on a custom condition. In this case, the custom condition is whether the build is a PR build or not.

You can check the pre-defined build variables available in Azure Devops [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts#build-variables) and you can see that there is a **Build.Reason** variable.

I am listing a few variables here.

- Manual: A user manually queued the build.
- IndividualCI: Continuous integration (CI) triggered by a Git push or a TFVC check-in.
- **PullRequest**: The build was triggered by a Git branch policy that requires a build.

You can specify the condition in custom condition settings of your build step like this. 
More examples [available in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=vsts&tabs=designer)
[image]